# Microsoft Graph API findMeetingTimes endpoint returning incorrect response

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Yesterday (December 16, 2020), I noticed that the findMeetingTimes endpoint started returning an empty response object (when testing using Graph Explorer) for requests that would previously result in some meetingTimeSuggestions.

I've been using this endpoint for a while and haven't changed how I interact with it.

Example:

```
{"attendees":[{"emailAddress":{"address":"<EMAIL>"},"type":"Required"}],"timeConstraint":{"timeslots":[{"start":{"dateTime":"2020-12-19T21:52:35.093Z","timeZone":"Pacific Standard Time"},"end":{"dateTime":"2020-12-26T21:52:35.093Z","timeZone":"Pacific Standard Time"}}]},"meetingDuration":"PT1H"}
```

Looking at the ["Find meeting times" documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-findmeetingtimes?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), I'm not seeing any major changes to the API (and the reference was last updated over a month ago).

**Any ideas on what might be going on?**

I've checked StackOverflow, the ["Known issues with Microsoft Graph" page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues), and Twitter, and I've also done some Googling but haven't found much on this.

Comment: Share the Graph API call that you tried

Comment: Just updated with an example for future reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually not empty, it's even weirder.  It started aggressively returning a gzip encoded body (violation of RFC) and ignoring Accept-Encoding header (NB: If you don't put "Accept-Encoding: gzip" it won't event *say* Content-Encoding:gzip but it is!)

I don't know how one can log an API bug, and tho I just paid for a "support package" it didn't apparently go through yet.  So I'm going to hack my back-end to detect the gzip magic bytes ( 1f 8b ) and gunzip it.

Comment: Thanks for this!

I was also seeing an encoded body in my actual response though the preview in Graph Explorer was showing an empty object.

Took another look today, and it seems like Microsoft picked up on the issue and fixed the issue.